# Convert observable<customObject> to customObject

Tags: angular

I have this to read a user from my firebase DB

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AppUser } from '../models/app-user';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
 

  get(uid:string) : AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
  }
}
```

Now I need to verify if this user is admin or not using `CanActivate`, I tired this but I have alywas an error.
I have difficulties to convert an observable to sample object

```
  constructor(private authService : AuthService,private router: Router,private userService : UserService) { }

  canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    let customUser : AngularFireObject<AppUser>;
     this.authService.userData$.pipe(
      switchMap( async user => customUser = this.userService.get(user?.uid || ""))

     )

  }
```

I have this config

```
Angular CLI: 11.1.0
Node: 14.15.4
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.4"
sudo firebase --version
9.5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CanActivate` does accept `Observable<boolean>` as a return type (see [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)) so you can simply return your observable which returns the boolean and angular will handle the rest:

```js
canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.authService.userData$.pipe(
    switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user?.uid || "").valueChanges()),
    map((res)=> res?.isAdmin || false)
}
```

Note: I assumed your `userService.get()` method returns `Observable<boolean>`

Comment: userService.get() return AngularFireObject<AppUser>

and the canActivate method that I wrote it's not complete
I have to check if the user that I get if admin or not
but I did not find a way to do that

Comment: @Rad Ah no problem. Then you can simply return `valueChanges()` which comes from the `AngularFireObject`. I've also added the map function where you can do your additional logic; check if user is admin etc. --e.g: `map((res)=> res.isAdmin)`

Comment: return this.authService.userData$.pipe(
     switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user?.uid || "").valueChanges()),
     map(res => res?.isAdmin || false))

I changed like this if I dont add this '|| false' I got this error Type 'Observable<boolean | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)

thank you bro

Comment: Ah that makes sense ofc :-) I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Thank you
and by the why do I have to unsubscribe for this?does this consume memory?I read that I have always to unsubscribe to Firebase observable

Comment: That might be true if you would use it in other places since these are "hot" observables but the authguards life is typically the same as the apps so you don't need to do it here. Besides Angular does handle authguard observable subscriptions so you have nothing to worry about